# Merging Excel Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two Excel spreadsheets with around 3,000 rows. The data for the first sheet looks like this:

```
SKU    | TITLE            
7261   | Red Sofa        
7262   | Blue Sofa        
7263   | Green Sofa       
7264   | Orange Sofa
```

The data for the second sheet (note the rows are now in a completely different order) looks like so:

```
SKU    |DESC                | PRICE
7261   |Different Desc      | £900
7264   |Different Desc      | £910
7262   |Different Desc      | £950
7263   |Different Desc      | £920
```

How do I merge the two sheets together so I have this?:

```
SKU   | TITLE               |DESC                | PRICE
7261  | Red Sofa            |Different Desc      | £900
7264  | Orange Sofa         |Different Desc      | £910
7262  | Blue Sofa           |Different Desc      | £950
7263  | Green Sofa          |Different Desc      | £920
```

Comment: You can use VLOOKUP() for this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Title` is in B1, in C1 copied across to D1 and then both formulae down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP($A1,second!$A:$C,COLUMN()-1,0)
```